# Laravel: WhereNull, OrWhere, is ignoring WhereRaw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my controller I am using Laravels `WhereNull`, `OrWhere` and `WhereRaw` in DB Query.  It is pulling in all the results but the problem is it looks like it is pulling in everything and ignoring the last Where clause.  I have used this in a different method on other controllers and it works fine.  Is there a specific order or something I am missing?

**Doesn't Work (Ignores WhereRaw and shows all results)**

```
$lists = DB::table('statuses')
                    ->whereNull('company_id')
                    ->orWhere('company_id', '=', Auth::user()->company_id)
                    ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('Task',assigned_to)")
                    ->get();
```

**This works in other controllers used as a different method without the whereRaw:**

```
return Status::whereNull('company_id')->orWhere('company_id', '=', Auth::user()->company_id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                    ->get();
```

**Sample DB**
[image]

Source link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Use `DB::raw` instead of `whereRaw`

```
->where(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET('Task',assigned_to)"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately that is giving me the same results so no change

Comment: Can you share query generated before and after using `toSql()`

Comment: Full query is found above below the line "Doesn't Work (Ignores WhereRaw and shows all results)". Let me know if you are looking for something else